# How to understand the effect of local_step in tf.ConditionalAccumulator()

Tags: tensorflow

I want to implement the function which conducts `backward()` after multiple `forward()` operations in order to increase the actual `batch_size` with limited GPU memory. So I came to `tf.ConditionalAccumulator`.

In the arguments of [`tf.ConditionalAccumulator().apply_grad()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ConditionalAccumulator#apply_grad), there is an argument `local_step` which I do not understand how to appoint. The document explains as follow:

> Attempts to apply a gradient to the accumulator.
>
> The attempt is silently dropped if the gradient is stale, i.e., local_step is less than the accumulator's global time step.
>
> Args:
>
> `grad`: The gradient tensor to be applied.
>
> `local_step`: Time step at which the gradient was computed.
>
> `name`: Optional name for the operation.

I tried to search the implementation of `tf.CondionalAccumentor().apply_grad()`, but didn't find the member variable refers to `global_time_step`. In my understanding, there should be ten gradient slots, if we want to accumulate 10 times before one gradient update. The `global_time_step` is applied as an indicator to point out which slot should be used. if the `local_step` is less than the `global_time_step`, which means the corresponding slot has been used, so the gradient is stale and should be discarded.

In my implementation, I assign it with `global_step` variable, which is used to record the number of gradient update in training procedure, and it increases one in every `batch_size` iterations, thus it increases one after `batch_size` examples forward. I am not sure about the correctness of my implementation.

I hope someone can help to explain the mechanism of `tf.ConditionalAccumulator`.